# Opera won't download into Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: downloads

I tried to download the Opera web browser into Ubuntu 11.10 from www.opera.com.  I followed the procedure, pressing the download button for Opera for Linux. If I "Save to disk", and then try to open the download, a window pops up that says "INTERNAL ERROR - The file /home/Bob/Desktop/opera...."etc.  Is Opera not compatible with Ubuntu 11.10?  It was with an earlier version of Ubuntu.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: in terminal run `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and add this line `deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free`, save changes and run `wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | apt-key add -` and than `apt-get update`, `apt-get install opera`

Comment: And it installs on 12.04 perfectly without resorting to any terminal commands. The download should be a .deb file and if you right-click on it and choose to install via the software center things should work.

Answer (score 0):

To install Opera in Ubuntu read below:

> There are two basic types of installations, static and shared:
>
> Static version: Opera has the Qt library built in. It is a larger
>   download, and it does not use antialiased fonts on menus or the file
>   chooser, and uses aliasing in the browser window and most other
>   interface elements.
>
> Shared version: Opera uses the Qt installation on your system. It
>   integrates with the system, using whatever anti aliasing setting you
>   have for other Qt applications.
>
> The shared version is probably better, as some of the resources it
>   uses (e.g., RAM for the Qt libraries) can be reused by other
>   applications. Try the other one if you run into installation or
>   operational problems.<sup>1</sup>

[Read On](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OperaBrowser)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Documentations](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OperaBrowser)</sup>